# Can I Start and End an OSM2PO route in the middle of a road segment?

Tags: routing, osm2po

I need to be able to start and end a route in the middle of a road segment as opposed to a vertex/intersection. I know that you can disable snapping when stating your start/end but the route still shows the start and end snapping to a vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since 4.5.25 it is possible, though Beta/Experimental.
There are some todos left, e.g. if a turn restriction follows the first segment, adjusting the SOAP-Service-Interface, using heuristics ...

For a first impression, start the WebTestUI as usual, disable snapping and select the OverlayRouter instead of the DefaultRouter...

Comment: It works great Carsten. This is an excellent update of OSM2PO. I need to check back on the OSM2PO site often, as I see you update frequently. I See what you mean with "if a turn restriction follows the first segment." This is a minor issue that I can work with, but will be looking forward to the fix. Great work as always with OSM2PO!

Comment: The issues above are fixed now. If you are interested in an intermediate version, please contact me via email.

Comment: Any idea when the official release is scheduled?